# Sync directory files to Google Cloud Composer dags/ folder

Tags: gcloud, gsutil, google-cloud-composer

I'd like to sync the contents of a folder in my repository to the GCP Composer `dags/` folder in a simple command.

The gcloud composer cli seems to have a command for this however it leaves a warning that support for wildcards is being removed.

```
>> gcloud composer environments storage dags import \
      --source="dir/*" \
      --environment={env_name} \
      --location={loc}
WARNING: Use of gsutil wildcards is no longer supported in --source. Set the storage/use_gsutil property to get the old behavior back temporarily. However, this property will eventually be removed.
```

Is there a way to use this command that has the same effect of expanding the contents of `dir` into the composer `dags/` folder that isn't being deprecated? I've looked into `gsutil rsync` but that command makes it very difficult to ignore certain files and directories. GCloud has a nice `.gcloudignore` file that handles this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `gsutil rsync`

```
gsutil rsync -r -c -x  -d local_directory gs://GCS-BUCKET-NAME/dags
```

This will make sure to sync between the local directory and the days dir every time you run this command. Also, its only updates the files that have been modified between source and destination directory.

Answer (score 2):

### Automated Solution

There is a way to do this automatically. You'll you use `Cloud Build` and `Cloud Repositories`.

First of all, create a repository on Cloud Source Repository, containing your dags and plugins. Add a file called `cloudbuild.yaml`, this will be responsible to sync your files with cloud storage.

```
├── cloudbuild.yaml
├── dags
│   └── airflow_monitoring.py
├── plugins
│   ├── hooks
│   │   └── my_hook.py
│   ├── operators
│   │   └── my_operator.py
│   └── sensors
│       └── my_sensor.py
```

Inside the `cloudbuild.yaml`, put the following:

```yaml
steps:
- name: ubuntu
  args: ['bash', '-c', "echo '$COMMIT_SHA' > REVISION.txt"]
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args:
    - '-m'
    - 'rsync'
    - '-d'
    - '-r'
    - 'dags'
    - 'gs://${_GCS_BUCKET}/dags'
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args:
    - '-m'
    - 'rsync'
    - '-d'
    - '-r'
    - 'plugins'
    - 'gs://${_GCS_BUCKET}/plugins'
```

Using `rsync` command, you can synchronize the files that have been modified between source and destination.

Now, go to `Cloud Build` and create a trigger with the following configuration:

The most important settings here is the Source (Which will be a repository) and Branch. Every push on this branch will trigger the build.

[image: settings - part 1]

In this second part, two things are import:

1 - The build configuration file (Don't worry about this step if you followed the same folder structure mentioned above. If you have changed the location of the `cloudbuild.yaml` file, inform the path where it is located in the repository)

2 - Create a variable called `_GCS_BUCKET` containing your Cloud Composer bucket name

[image: settings - part 2]

Then, just click on `create` and now, your files on repository will synchronize with your Cloud Composer bucket every time that you push something to master branch.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, wildcards is no longer supported in `--source`.

Use of `gcloud composer` command is probably more robust and of course you don't need to specify the bucket name. So, I used a for loop to import DAGs into the root of DAGs folder. The gcloud command may respect the [.gcloudignore](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) file too.

```
for entry in "$DAG_DIRECTORY"/*; do \
    gcloud composer environments storage dags import \
    --environment $GOOGLE_CLOUD_COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT \
    --location $GOOGLE_CLOUD_LOCATION \
    --project $GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT \
    --source "$entry"; \
done
```

Comment: but there must be a reason why they no longer support wildcards. I am always afraid of doing this.
For more complex dags this is the way to go of course

Answer (score 0):

The command `gcloud composer environments storage dags import` imports from local storage into the cloud composer bucket. It seems that it doesn't synchronizes the source and destination. In the [examples](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/storage/dags/import), the existing files in the `dags/` folder are not deleted, only new files are added.

Given the fact that the gcloud command only copies the source content to the `dags/` folder, the gsutil can help:

```
gsutil cp -r dir/* gs://composer-bucket/dags
```

Comment: "[...] the existing files in the dags/ folder are not deleted, only new files are added." That's not exactly true. The existing files are overwritten.